# Comportamento enter no formulário ReactJS

Tags: react

Estou tendo o seguinte problema no ReactJS.

- Quando pressiono enter ele está enviando o formulário e eu gostaria de retirar esse comportamento.
  Segue exemplo do código:

```
import React from "react";

export function Teste() {
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit");
  }
  function handleKeyPress(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="text"
          onKeyPress={(event) => handleKeyPress(event)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- Solução que achei

```
import React from "react";

export function Teste() {
 function handleSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log("submit");
 }
 function handleKeyPress(event) {
   console.log(event.key);
   if (event.key === "Enter") {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
 }
 return (
   <div>
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <input
         type="text"
         id="text"
         onKeyPress={(event) => handleKeyPress(event)}
       />
       <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
     </form>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: Este é um comportamento padrão de formulário. Você realmente quer mudar isso? É uma regra de negócio?

Comment: Sim @CarlosQuerioz, preciso mudar isso porque o usuário está tendo problema ao adicionar as tags. 
- ele pressiona enter para add um tag só que está enviando o formulário junto.

Comment: Não vou colocar uma resposta ali, mas acho que vc precisa capturar o evento de tecla pressionada. Talvez validar também em qual campo está. Se não conseguir aí tento elaborar uma resposta pra ti.

Comment: Qual é o motivo de tirar o comportamento padrão? em qual dos eventos está fazendo isso já visto que seu código tem duas funções?

Comment: Coloquei a Solução que achei, na pergunta.
Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia, você pode resolver esse problema utilizando um onKeyDown={null} no seu input submit, isso deve prevenir esse comportamento indesejado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).